# SQL: Asking a MAX Result after a MIN Query

Tags: sql, database, select

I'm trying to write a query where I select the highest Speed out of the PCs with the Lowest Ram.

Using this SQL Statement

```
Select DISTINCT RAM FROM PC WHERE RAM = (Select MIN(RAM) FROM PC);
```

Gives this Result:

```
RAM
512
```

Using this SQL Statement

```
Select Speed, Ram From PC WHERE Speed = (Select Max(Speed) from PC WHERE Ram = (Select DISTINCT RAM FROM PC WHERE RAM = (Select MIN(RAM) FROM PC)));
```

Gives this result

```
Speed RAM
3.2   512
3.2   1024
```

What am I doing wrong in my query?  The second record should not be showing as we have already selected the Min(RAM)

**Sample Data:**

```
CREATE TABLE PC (   model INT PRIMARY KEY,
                  speed NUMBER (4,2),
                  ram INT,
                        hd INT,
                  price NUMBER (7,2)
                );

INSERT INTO PC VALUES (1001, 3.66, 1024, 250, 2114);
INSERT INTO PC VALUES (1002, 2.10, 512, 250, 995);
INSERT INTO PC VALUES (1003, 1.42, 512, 80, 478);
INSERT INTO PC VALUES (1004, 2.80, 1024, 250, 649);
INSERT INTO PC VALUES (1005, 3.20, 512, 250, 630);
INSERT INTO PC VALUES (1006, 3.20, 1024, 320, 1049);
INSERT INTO PC VALUES (1007, 2.20, 1024, 200, 510);
INSERT INTO PC VALUES (1008, 2.20, 2048, 250, 770);
INSERT INTO PC VALUES (1009, 2.00, 1024, 250, 650);
INSERT INTO PC VALUES (1010, 2.80, 2048, 300, 770);
INSERT INTO PC VALUES (1011, 1.86, 2048, 160, 959);
INSERT INTO PC VALUES (1012, 2.80, 1024, 160, 649);
INSERT INTO PC VALUES (1013, 3.06, 512, 80, 529);
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. For future information, when you added the SQL tag you were shown a large popup that suggested you add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, because syntax and functionality varies between them. It's there for a reason: *Syntax and functionality varies between different DBMSs, so it helps when you tell us which one you're using.* Please don't ignore it.

Comment: I'll add the DB Type in the future.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overcomplicate things.

For selecting the minimum ram, you can shorten you statement to this:

```
SELECT MIN(RAM) FROM PC
```

For selecting the maximum speed for the minimum ram, use this:

```
SELECT MAX(speed) FROM PC where RAM = (SELECT MIN(RAM) FROM PC)
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't too difficult using analytic functions:

```
SELECT model, speed, ram, price
FROM
(
    SELECT model, speed, ram, price, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY speed DESC) rn2
    FROM
    (
        SELECT model, speed, ram, price, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ram) rn1
        FROM PC
    ) t
    WHERE rn1 = 1
) t
WHERE rn2 = 1;
```

The advantage of this approach is that it returns the entire matching records.

Comment: Um... This doesn't answer the question asked (getting max speed for the min RAM). It also seems like vast over-complication for a pretty simple query. (Not downvoting, just saying...)

Comment: @KenWhite This _does_ find all records with the min RAM, then finds the records having the max speed from among those min records.  Often, the follow up to a question like this will be "what about the other columns?"  The accepted answer won't help much there.